# Is it possible to learn Node.js without knowing JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am a beginner and i am trying to learn Node.js.

- is it absolutely necessary to know JavaScript to master Node.js?
- I did tried execute some programs of Node.js on my local-host and
  server, so I am really beginning to like Node.js
- I have executed programs like Hello World, writing and reading a file,
  starting a server, etc.

I know Node.js works on JavaScript. I know some basics of JavaScript, but do I need to have deep knowledge of JavaScript?

Comment: It's like asking "I want to drive a car, but do I really need to learn the traffic rules?" YES, of course!

Comment: Node.JS is a toolkit built around Javascript, so yes, to get _good_ at it would require Javascript knowledge. That said, you _can_ program in Typescript and possibly Coffeescript instead, which are both similar in concepts to, but not identical to, Javascript.

Comment: all resource to learn MEAN stack .....https://www.reddit.com/r/meanstack/comments/2v68zd/mean_js/

Answer (score 14):

This is like saying, "do I need to learn French to be able to sing French songs"? Well, you can just learn the words and how to say them, but you won't be able to make any French song yourself if you don't know French.

And I'm really comparing song composition to programming. You can copy and paste stuff into Javascript files without knowing what it really does, but it doesn't help you do something yourself.

In the end, yes, you need to know the language you're working with if you want to build anything. You don't need to be all-knowing to get started, though. If you try to understand what you're doing, you'll most certainly learn stuff along the way.

Comment: Nice comparison, however the complexity of programming requires a fundamental understanding of the concepts and the language you use, so you won't be able to do anything if you don't know the language well. Most likely one will fail the next easy problem which deviates from the tutorial by just a bit (but would be easily solvable if you knew what you where doing).

Comment: I think song composition pretty much covers that @Christoph.

Comment: @Christoph, you'll probably agree that you have to start somewhere. I started programming by fiddling with phpBB about ten years ago in my early teens and I sure read a lot of tutorials.

Answer (score 13):

I suggest you spend a little time learning the basics of Javascript (there's not much to it), and then jump right into node.js and start writing sample apps. Most of the concepts you need to learn for node.js come from the standard ys1382-code-learning-process (tm):

1. read a tutorial, understand maybe 10%
2. download the tutorial's final code, without bothering to go through all the steps
3. try modify the tutorial code to do something a little different, without breaking everything
4. write your own trivial app, with lots of googling.
5. ?
6. profit

At least that's what works for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you never had any knowledges in programming, then i agree  with zneak.
And if you know already other programming languages C or C# or Java, then yes, you can.

Comment: Funny to list class-based languages with typing who don't have functions as first class objects. I would agree if you had written: `if you know already other programming languages Self, Io or Scala, then yes, you can.` ;)

Comment: Well, you get the idea :) .

Comment: all things you will get  here  https://www.reddit.com/r/meanstack/comments/2v68zd/mean_js/